# How does Confluent's Schema Registry assign schema id's?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I'm using the `CachedSchemaRegistryClient` and the `register` method, which takes a subject and `Avro` schema.  I'm running these against the `5.2.1` confluent docker images, and when I register the schema I get back behavior that I find strange.

The first schema I register returns an `id` of `81` (backed up by using the schema registry REST api to check that this schema is tied to this `id`), and then the second schema returns and id of 121.

Since this behavior is unexpected and I have been unable to find an answer via Google, I'm curious if there is a hashing strategy or something similar to assign schema ids, I would expect it to start at 1 and increment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Confluent Documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/index.html#schema-management) explains how unique IDs are assigned to schemas:

> Schema Registry is a distributed storage layer for Avro Schemas which
>   uses Kafka as its underlying storage mechanism. Some key design
>   decisions:
>
> - **Assigns globally unique ID to each registered schema. Allocated IDs
>     are guaranteed to be monotonically increasing but not necessarily
>     consecutive.**
> - Kafka provides the durable backend, and functions as a
>     write-ahead changelog for the state of Schema Registry and the schemas
>     it contains.
> - Schema Registry is designed to be distributed, with
>     single-primary architecture, and ZooKeeper/Kafka coordinates primary
>     election (based on the configuration).

Also,

> **[Schema ID Allocation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/index.html#schema-id-allocation)**
>
> Schema ID allocation always happens in the primary node and Schema IDs
>   are always monotonically increasing.
>
> If you are using Kafka primary election, the Schema ID is always based
>   off the last ID that was written to Kafka store. During a primary
>   re-election, batch allocation happens only after the new primary has
>   caught up with all the records in the store `<kafkastore.topic>`.
>
> If you are using ZooKeeper primary election,
>   `/<schema.registry.zk.namespace>/schema_id_counter` path stores the
>   upper bound on the current ID batch, and new batch allocation is
>   triggered by both primary election and exhaustion of the current
>   batch. This batch allocation helps guard against potential
>   zombie-primary scenarios, (for example, if the previous primary had a
>   GC pause that lasted longer than the ZooKeeper timeout, triggering
>   primary reelection).